# Problem with Symbolic toolbox of MATLAB 2010b, 32bit, installed in UBUNTU 12.04 LTS, 64-bit

Tags: matlab

I have installed 32-bit MATLAB 2010b on 64-bit UBUNTU 12.04 LTS according to the instructions given in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB). It is doing fine except the symbolic toolbox package. Whenever I try to run a command like 'sym a' or any other command that needs use of symbolic toolbox, it becomes busy. The program cannot be terminated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. The terminal, from where MATLAB was launched, reads:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/toolbox/symbolic/mupad/share//bin/mupkern: 115: exec: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/toolbox/symbolic/mupad/glnxa64/bin/mupkern: not found
```

Need your advice on how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/toolbox/symbolic/mupad/glnx86 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/toolbox/symbolic/mupad/glnxa64
```

in terminal will solve it. A similar problem is reported here: http://www.mathworks.co.jp/support/solutions/en/data/1-O7POO/